# backend and frontend setup for Yii

Tags: yii, frontend, backend

Currently I have 2 install setups of Yii for both my backend and frontend. But while working on this it gets abit confusing and I was wondering if this done in the right way. Below is an example how my folder structure is setup.

```
- backend
  - assets
  - css
  - images
  - js
  - protected
         - components
         - config
                main.php

         - controllers
         - data
         - extensions
         - models
         - modules
         - runtime
         - views
              - layouts
              - site

         .htaccess
         yiic
         yiic.php

  - themes
  - upload
  index.php
  .htaccess


frontend

  - assets
  - css
  - images
  - protected
         - commands
         - components
         - config
                main.php

         - controllers
         - data
         - extensions
         - models
         - modules
         - runtime
         - views
              - layouts
              - site

         .htaccess
         yiic
         yiic.php

  - themes
  index.php
  .htaccess
```

Can anyway tell me of this is a good way. Or is it a stupid way. What is the normal way to do this. I have looked into documentation but it's all uncomplete or not specific. What I want is the most common way to setup a backend and frontend structure for Yii.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/33/organize-directories-for-applications-with-front-end-and-back-end/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My opinion, the best way is do not break encapsulation and use setup like the following:

- http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/63/organize-directories-for-applications-with-front-end-and-back-end-using-webapplicationend-behavior/
- http://habrahabr.ru/post/117457/ (russian)

In this case:

- you will be able to store all controllers and views in one place
- on module structure(when you will use it) that will not break their encapsulation and you will be able easy to share their between your sites

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at the directory structure of the Yii Project Site 
[YiiProject Directory Structure](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/155/the-directory-structure-of-the-yii-project-site)
OR download the yii Boilerplate by Clevertech and take a look at their Folder Structure.Here is the link [YiiBoilerplate](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/374/yiiboilerplate-setup-a-professional-project-structure-in-seconds/)